# QML ListView that fits the chosen style

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to create a simple GUI, and I need to display a selectable list with multiple rows in each entry. I'm using Material as the main style, but it doesn't look like Material. Is there a way to connect the delegates to Material Design or dynamically when I change to another style like Universal?

````
         Component {
             id: contactDelegate
             Item {
                 width: 180; height: 40
                 Column {
                     Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                     Text { text: '<b>Number:</b> ' + number }
                 }
                 MouseArea {
                     anchors.fill: parent
                     onClicked:{

                         myList.currentIndex = index
                         myList.focus = true
                          console.log( style.toLocaleString())
                     }
                 }
             }
         }


         ListView {
             id: myList
             anchors.fill: parent
             model: ContactModel {}
             delegate: contactDelegate
             highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightgreen"; radius: 5 }
             focus: true
             addDisplaced: Transition {
                 NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 1000 }
             }
             clip: true
         }```
````

Comment: Does it work if you use [Label](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-label.html) instead of `Text`?

Comment: The *Material style* doesn't affect your custom raw components. It is your responsibility to design a *Material style compatible component*. In this case, you can follow the [Google Material Design Guidelines](https://m2.material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html).